# Custom List Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

How i do a custom list fragment,like this [Custom list view](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/),but for list fragment..

Is this the same way? because in listfragment we declare  in xml..

Answer (score 2):

You can extend ListFragment like any other class. You can then reference your own custom class in the xml with:

```
<my.package.location.MyListFragment .../>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the problems you are having together with the code you are using.

Comment: I just put that part of code that u wrote above but it cant find any xml parameter,like android:layout_width...

Comment: Have you created the Java class first?

Comment: Then it is very hard to say what the problem is. I would need to see both the xml and java code and also the exact error.

Comment: I did what u said... Extends my class with ListFragment and then put in xml <my.package.myClass>. But cant find xml android parameters,